# How to develop window apps in PHP?

Tags: php

How to start with windows application for windows mobile phone in PHP, can any one have good suggestion for starter, is there any tutorial for fresher.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I'd recommend learning C# and WPF

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion, is to keep your distance.

PHP is meant for web pages. Unless what you mean is to to create Web applications for desktop and mobile devices I would skip on PHP.

If you insist, chances are that you can use [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/) ontop of .NET to run PHP. That way you can use PHP to create WinForms Applications for example. Really, if you are going to use .NET, you will probably be better suited by learning C# or VB.NET.

Please also check http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/mobile-app-development/ may be it what you are looking.

Comment: There are webapps, maybe he's not looking for native?

Comment: @DaveChen although not exactly "native" since it is on .NET, you could use Phalanger for desktop applications. I remember there were templates for Class Library, WinForms and Console Application..

Comment: Above link is helpful for mine, i think mobile app is tough by using PHP.